# Can I use ELMAH to log exceptions which occurs in Entity framework classes?

Tags: elmah

I have two separate projects, one for EF and another for MVC. And added reference of EF project to MVC project.

Now, I am trying to use ELMAH to log errors from MVC application, and it's working fine with MVC exceptions.
But I have one question, if any exception occurs in EF classes then can elmah will log that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, I asked very simple question in curiosity.
I used elmah to log errors from mvc application. My mvc application uses EF as ORM.

To log errors which occurs at EF, I used try-catch, with throw.
Which pass errors to mvc application.

Comment: Nice, was looking for a solution too for this with Elmah.